# Не устанавливается Node.js

Tags: node.js, windows, установка, msi

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему
установила node, но в Power Shell она не отображалась, после чего я ее удалила, перезагрузила ноут и пытаюсь установить заново. В начале установки предлагает change way или repair или remove, перепробовала все, не получается, каждый раз вылезает вот такое предупреждение и установка прерывается. Безопасный режим Windows отключен. На ноут установились Install Additional Tools for Node.js и Node.js command promt, и я не могу их ни восстановить, ни удалить. [image: не устанавливается node.js]

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите более подробнее что именно вы делаете и с какими трудностями столкнулись. Покажите логи.

Comment: установила node, но в Power Shell она не отображалась, после чего я ее удалила, перезагрузила ноут и пытаюсь установить заново. В начале установки предлагает change way или repair или remove, перепробовала все, не получается, каждый раз вылезает вот такое предупреждение и установка прерывается. Безопасный режим Windows отключен.

Comment: Не в комментарий, правьте вопрос :)

Comment: блин у меня сейчас такая же проблема, подскажите кто решил

Answer (score 0):

Переименой msi-инсталлятор и переложи его в такую папку, чтобы ни в имени, ни в пути не было пробелов и кириллицы. Но только не в корень диска.

PS: Была раньше такая проблема с msi, к nodejs не имеет никакого отношения. Впрочем, я не уверен, что это именно она, да и там какая-то специфика была, чтобы она проявилась.